# Ninjaframework MVC Controller inheritance and routing

Tags: java, model-view-controller, ninjaframework

In my Ninja Web Application,I've a generic controller for CRUD operation.

Generic Interface:

```
interface GenericController <T, PK> {
    Result read(PK id);
}
```

Abstract Controller:

```
abstract class AbstractController<T, PK extends Serializable> implements GenericController<T, PK>{
    @Override
    public Result read(PK id) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Foo Controller:

```
@Singleton
@Path("/foo")
public class FooController extends AbstractController<FooDto, Long>{
    @Path("/{id}")
    @GET
    @Override
    public Result read(@PathParam("id") Long id) {
    }
}
```

When I run my ninja webapp, this error occurred:

```
[NinjaJetty] ERROR ninja.RouteBuilder - Error in route configuration!!!
[NinjaJetty] ERROR ninja.RouteBuilder - Can not find Controller controllers.FooController and method read
[NinjaJetty] ERROR ninja.RouteBuilder - Hint: make sure the controller returns a ninja.Result!
[NinjaJetty] ERROR ninja.RouteBuilder - Hint: Ninja does not allow more than one method with the same name!
[NinjaJetty] ERROR ninja.RouteBuilder - Error in route configuration!!!
[NinjaJetty] ERROR ninja.RouteBuilder - Can not find Controller controllers.FooController and method read
[NinjaJetty] ERROR ninja.RouteBuilder - Hint: make sure the controller returns a ninja.Result!
[NinjaJetty] ERROR ninja.RouteBuilder - Hint: Ninja does not allow more than one method with the same name!
[NinjaJetty] ERROR ninja.RouteBuilder - Can not find Controller controllers.FooController and method read
[NinjaJetty] ERROR ninja.RouteBuilder - Hint: make sure the controller returns a ninja.Result!
[NinjaJetty] ERROR ninja.RouteBuilder - Hint: Ninja does not allow more than one method with the same name!
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a java bug. see bug report [java 8](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8142904) and [java 6](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6815786).